# Arguments with quotations(" ") to be not escaped

Tags: perl, scripting

I am writing a Perl script which enables the addition and modification of parameters maintained in a particular file.
The script takes the following arguments; Parameter name($paraName), Parameter value($paraVal) and the file ($profile).
The script checks if the parameter($paraName) exists already. if it does, it just changes the value($paraVal) else adds both the parameter($paraName) and the value($paraVal) to the file($profile).

Following is the block of code for the same:

```
   print "  checking if parameter is already avaialable";
   my $response = system("egrep -qs  \"$paraName =\" $profile");
   $rc = 1;
   if ($response == 0) {
    print "  Parameter is already available, changing the value now! ";
    $rc = system("sed -i 's:.*$paraName.*:$paraName = $paraVal \# Parameter changed by $script:' $profile");
    print "   Parameter $paraName has been updated with the value $paraVal in the Profile successfully \n\n";
   }
   else{
    print "  Parameter is not available, Adding the Paremeter now! ";
    $rc = system("echo \"$paraName = $paraVal \# Parameter added by $script\" >> $profile");
    print "   Parameter $paraName has been added with the value $paraVal in the Profile successfully \n\n";
   }
```

The script works fine for most cases, except when I have arguments with double quotes to be added as a new parameter. It works file for hash(#), slashes (), etc, when passes within a single quote(' ').

This is working in case of changing the value($paraVal) when the parameter($paraName) already exists. But while a new parameter has to be added, this fails to add double quotes in the parameter name.

Would appreciate some help here.

Comment: Can you give an example of a `$paraName` and what would be the expected content of `$profile` after adding? Also give an example of how you call the script

Comment: You definitely has code injection bugs. Why are you even shelling out instead of doing it in Perl?

Comment: You might be able to fix the problem by using single quotes instead of escaped double quotes `\"` for the first argument to `egrep` and to `echo`

Comment: @HåkonHægland, $profile is the name of the file which will be edited.(it's very use-case specific and so I have left out the details). an example of the $paraName would be: "PA_SSED". 
I am already using single quotes to accommodate for special characters. But that fails in case of lets' say, ' "PA_SSED" ', will still just write PA_SSED into the file.

Comment: @ikegami, I am not quite sure if I understand. Are you talking about using 'echo'? I would appreciate if you would correct me and tell me a better way, I am quite new to Perl.

Comment: @AashishCherian the key comment that ikegami is making is you using "system" to execute commands that can be dealt with natively in Perl code.

Comment: @ikegami, I am not too concerned about code injection at this moment as I have a block of code that takes care of validating the inputs.

Comment: Re "*I am not too concerned about code injection at this moment*", Actually, the problem you are asking about is the direct result of the code injection bug (the failure to properly build the shell command).

Comment: @ikegami, thanks for pointing out, I think now I get what you mean. I am going to try with pure perl approach. But I was under the impression that ability to use Shell commands in Perl was a powerful feature and one of the reasons to be widely used by systems admins.

Comment: You can easily shell out from any language, including Perl. It's wasteful, and it makes error checking harder and less precise. It's wasteful because Perl is actually known for how easy it makes using regular expressions.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example of how you could write it as pure Perl:

```
use feature qw(say);
use strict;
use warnings;

my ( $paraName, $paraVal, $profile ) = @ARGV;
my $script = $0;

open ( my $fh, '<', $profile ) or die "Could not open file '$profile': $!";
my $found = 0;
while( my $line = <$fh> ) {
    chomp $line;
    if ( my ($key) = $line =~ /^(\Q$paraName\E)\s*=\s*/) {
        say "$key = $paraVal \# Parameter changed by $script";
        $found = 1;
    }
    else {
        say $line;
    }
}
close $fh;
if ( !$found ) {
    say "$paraName = $paraVal \# Parameter added by $script";
}
```

**Edit**:

The above script does not modify the profile file, but instead writes the modified file to standard output. So it was meant to be used together with Shell redirection to save the output to a new file. To modify the profile file directly, you could use:

```
use feature qw(say);
use strict;
use warnings;

die "Bad arguments!" if @ARGV != 3;
my ( $paraName, $paraVal, $profile ) = @ARGV;
my $script = $0;
@ARGV = ( $profile );
$^I = '.bak';
my $found = 0;
while (my $line = <<>>) {
    chomp $line;
    if ( my ($key) = $line =~ /^(\Q$paraName\E)\s*=\s*/) {
        say "$key = $paraVal \# Parameter changed by $script";
        $found = 1;
    }
    else {
        say $line;
    }
} continue {
    say "$paraName = $paraVal \# Parameter added by $script" if eof && !$found;
}
```

This will first save the original profile file to a backup file with `.bak` extension, and then overwrite the profile file with the modified content.

Comment: Thanks for the example, for some reason it's not appending to the file though.

Comment: I think you need to redirect the output of the script to a new file. Currently, it is just printing to standard output (and not modifying the file)

Comment: It's required to modify the file itself. Will add that part. thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Try following code as alternative

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use feature 'say';

use Pod::Usage;
use Getopt::Long;
use Data::Dumper;

my %opt;        # program options
my %param;      # parameters storage
my $fh;         # file handle

GetOptions (
                'file|f=s'      => \$opt{file},
                'name|n=s'      => \$opt{name},
                'value|v=s'     => \$opt{value},
                'operation|o=s' => \$opt{op},
                'help|h'        => \$opt{help},
                'man|m'         => \$opt{man},
                'debug|d'       => \$opt{debug}
            ) or pod2usage(1);

pod2usage(1) if $opt{help};
pod2usage(-exitval => 0, -versose => 2) if $opt{man};

pod2usage(1) unless $opt{file};

open $fh, "< $opt{file}"
        or die "Couldn't open $opt{file}";

my @lines = <$fh>;

close $fh;

chomp @lines;

print Dumper(\@lines) if $opt{debug};

push @lines, "$opt{name} = $opt{value}"
            if $opt{op} eq 'add';

@lines = map { /$opt{name}\s*=/ ? '' : $_ } @lines
            if $opt{op} eq 'del';

@lines = map {
    s/($opt{name})\s*=\s*(.*)/$1 = $opt{value}/; $_
} @lines    if $opt{op} eq 'mod';

map{ say } @lines
            if $opt{op} eq 'view';

map {
    /$opt{name}\s*=\s*(.*)/ and say 'Verify: '
    . ($1 eq $opt{value} ? 'ok' : 'no')
} @lines    if $opt{op} eq 'check';

my %save = map { $_ => 1 } qw/add del mod/;

print Dumper(\@lines) if $opt{debug};

if( $save{ $opt{op} } ) {
    open $fh, "> $opt{file}"
            or die "Couldn't open $opt{file}";

    map { say $fh $_ } @lines;

    close $fh;
}

__END__

=head1 NAME

program - modify configuration file

=head1 SYNOPSIS

program [options] [file ...]

 Usage:
    program -op [add|del|mod|view|check] -n param -v value -f file
 Options:
    --file,-f       configuration filename
    --name,-n       parameter name
    --value,-v      parameter value
    --operation,-o  operation to perform
    --help,-h       brief help message
    --man,-m        full documentation
    --debug,-d      debug mode

=head1 OPTIONS

=over 8

=item B<--file,-f>

Configuration file to edit

=item B<--name,-n>

Configuration parameter name to operate on

=item B<--value,-v>

Configuration parameter value to operate on

=item B<--operation,-o>

Operation to perform on parameter: add, del, mod, view, check

=item B<--debug,-d>

Debug flag to print debug messages.

=item B<--help,-h>

Print a brief help message and exits.

=item B<--man,-m>

Prints the manual page and exits.

=back

=head1 DESCRIPTION

B<This program> allows to operate on configuation files variables.

=head1 AUTHOR

B<Polar Bear> L<https://stackoverflow.com/users/12313309/polar-bear>

=cut
```

Comment: This works out, I have only tried the add and mod options. In the case of my solution approach, I don't want the user to be worried about giving options of add or mod, if the parameter exists already, it will just change it else will add it as a new parameter.
This also takes care of duplicate parameters.
I would upvote the answer, but I don't have enough reputation points.